# Websites in Firefox using only half of the screen

Tags: firefox

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I've installed Gnome3 on it.

Firefox used to run normally, but one day I used the "snap" feature to snap it to the left and then maximized it again. The websites however refuse to use the rest of the screen and instead use only the left half (actually close to 70%) as shown in the screenshot.

[image: [Screenshot][1] (I can't post the image directly, don't have enough rep.)]

I haven't faced this problem with any other application, and any number of application restarts or system restarts (including switching to Unity) haven't helped.

If it helps, I was using the Tree Style Tab extension to display my tabs in a sidebar on the left, but disabling the extension hasn't helped, as the screenshot shows.

How can I get it back to normal?

Comment: Does this appear in Unity, too? (Log out, then before logging in again choose "Ubuntu" as session.)

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Try to create a new user profile. Hit (Alt+F2) and run 'firefox -profilemanager'

Comment: ... or switch to the Beta channel and try the "magical" new Reset Firefox feature (it'll erase potentially problematic data like extensions, but keep other stuff like bookmarks, history, saved passwords, etc intact). Check it out: http://blog.mozilla.org/verdi/166/the-new-reset-firefox-feature-is-like-magic/

Comment: A new profile worked, as well as disabling and re-enabling all my extensions. Still not sure where exactly the problem was. Fixed for me though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I checked the screen resolution and found it to be less then maximum. After maximizing it, in settings -> display, it again took up the whole screen.
I did not think that it would be that easy!

Comment: I can't verify your answer, as I can't reproduce the problem again. That could have been the problem; I've been switching resolutions because of switching between my laptop screen and my 24-inch monitor.